# HTML input element only letters, numbers and only one space

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input

I am trying to perform a validation while the user writes so that the input only accepts uppercase as well as lowercase letters, numbers and a single space between words. The input text should also not start or end with space.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#input-tags').on('keypress', function(e) {
    // Get tag value from input
    let tag = $(this).val();

    // Pattern for ignore special characters
    let actualChar = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    let dontHaveSpecial = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*[ ]?[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(actualChar); //return true if not exists special chars, else false
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      dontHaveSpecial = true;
    } // 13 is enter
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
      dontHaveSpecial = true;
    } // 9 is tab
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      dontHaveSpecial = true;
    } // 32 is space
    if (tag.startsWith(' ') || tag.endsWith(' ')) {
      tag = tag.trim();
    } //Tag starts or ends with space

    //Check spaces count
    let spacesCount = [...tag].filter(s => s === ' ').length;
    if (spacesCount > 1) {

      //Remove extra spaces
      let spaceIndex = tag.indexOf(' ');
      let newTag = tag.substring(spaceIndex + 1).trim();
      $(this).val(newTag);
    }

    // Prevent input if have special
    return dontHaveSpecial;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-tags">
```

But it does not work properly, since it allows more than one space and also eliminates letters and numbers when what I want to remove are the extra spaces.

Comment: Isn't a test on `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?: [A-Za-z0-9]+)*$` enough?

Comment: You test your regex only against the character that is being entered. Not the whole string.

Comment: Your question is about _validation_, but code is about _transform_. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the regex against the value after you apply the change from `actualChar`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#input-tags').on('keypress', function(e) {
    // we can skip the regex test for these cases
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      return true;
    } // 13 is enter
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
      return true;
    } // 9 is tab

    let actualChar = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

    // Get tag value from input
    let tag = $(this).val();

    // the result after the key is pressed
    let result = tag.substr(0, e.target.selectionStart) + actualChar + tag.substr(e.target.selectionEnd);

    // Pattern for ignore special characters
    return /^[A-Za-z0-9]+[ ]?[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(result); //return true if not exists special chars, else false

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-tags">
```

1. Put the special cases that always return `true` at the beginning.
2. Get the input `actualChar` and the current value of the input `tag`.
3. Create the result by replacing the selection (see example image
   below).
4. Check the result matches the pattern. If not, return false and
   ignore the input.

[image: selection]

Note that since it is possible to put a space between the words you might end up with a value that ends with one.
To deal with that you need to `trim` the value before using it.